# Conditional expectations with sigma-algebras and indicator functions

Tags: measure-theory

I am trying to wrap my head around conditional expectations with sigma algebra like the one below. Did I answer it correctly? If not, where did I go wrong?

> Let $\Omega = [0,1]$, $\Sigma = $ Borel sets on $\Omega$. $P=$ Lebesgue measure. Define $X(\omega) = \omega$ and $Y(\omega)=3I_{[0,\frac{1}{2})}(\omega) + 2I_{[\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4}]}(\omega)$ where $I(\cdot)$ denotes the indicator function. Evaluate (a) $E[X\mid \sigma(Y)]$ and (b) $E[Y\mid \sigma(X)]$.

Here is my attempt:

For (a):

If $Y=2$ then $\omega \in [\frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{4})$ so $E[X|Y=2]=\cfrac{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{3}{4}}{2}=\frac{5}{8}$. Similarly, if $Y=3$ then $E[X|Y=3]=\frac{1}{4}$. So

$$E[X|\sigma(Y)]=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{4} & \text{if}\quad \omega\in[0,\frac{1}{2})\\
\frac{5}{8} & \text{if}\quad \omega\in [\frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{4}]
\end{cases}.
$$

For (b):

$$E[Y|\sigma(X)]=
\sum_y yP[Y=y|\sigma(X)] = 
2\cdot\frac{1}{2}  +
3\cdot\frac{1}{4} = 1 + \frac{3}{4}=\frac{7}{4}.
$$

Comment: Hi, I think there's a typo on the forth line, starting at $Y(\omega)...$. Could you try to fix it, and then maybe I'll be able to understand your variable's definitions. ;)

Comment: @AlejandroNasifSalum, I was away for a while. Thanks for pointing that out. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculations for (a) are right (although incomplete) and I think you have a good intuition, but I would adjust notation and proof details.

For instance, true that if $Y=2$ that means $\omega \in \left[\tfrac12,\tfrac34\right]$ (actually you interchanged a parenthesis and a bracket somewhere—of course this is not a problem with Lebesgue measure, but better to have it always right). This means that
$$E(X|Y=2)=E\left(X(\omega)|\omega\in\left[\tfrac12,\tfrac34\right]\right)=\frac{\int_I X(\omega)dP}{\int_I dP},$$
where $I=\left[\tfrac12,\tfrac34\right]$.

Then you can say that $\int_I X(\omega)dP=\int_I \omega dP=\int_{1/2}^{3/4} \omega \: d\omega$, the last equality justified by the fact that $X(\omega)=\omega$ is Riemann integrable. So you will have $\int_I X(\omega)dP=\tfrac12\left(\left(\tfrac34\right)^2 - \left(\tfrac12\right)^2\right)=\tfrac5{32}$. Likewise $\int_I dP=\tfrac14$, so we finally get
$$E(X|Y=2)=\frac{\tfrac5{32}}{\tfrac14}=\frac58,$$
just as you calculated. Maybe you could make it easier saying (or better: proving) that $X_{|Y=2}\sim\mathcal{U}\left[\tfrac12,\tfrac34\right]$, but that of course depends on you're background or on the specific commands you were given.

By the way, you forgot to consider the case $Y=0$ which is equivalent to $\omega>\tfrac34$, so your final answer is not correct, which you can assume when you see that $E(X|\sigma(Y))$ is not defined for every $\omega \in \Omega$ (and it should, since $E(X|\sigma(Y))$ is actually a random variable).

Regarding (b), I don't quite get your reasoning, but is clearly not the right answer since, again, $E(Y|\sigma(X))$ is by definition a random variable, that is, a measurable function from $\Omega$ to $[0,1]\subset \mathbb R$.

Think it this way: all you need to know to determine the value of $Y$ is whether $\left[0,\tfrac12\right)$, $\left[\tfrac12,\tfrac34\right]$ or $\left(\tfrac34,1\right]$ happened, and these clearly belong to $\sigma(X)$ (they're all the inverse image by $X$ of some borelian set). So knowing $X$ you know $\omega$, and then you now the value of $Y(\omega)$ with probability 1; that value, of course, happens to be the (conditional) expectation.

(By the way, maybe you can try and guess which sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\Sigma=\mathcal{B}$ is $\sigma(X)$...)